# Как woocommerce хранит свои мета-данные?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Чем в woocommerce отличаются таблицы `postmeta` и `order_itemmeta`?
Эти две таблицы хранят данные заказа, почему нельзя хранить только в одной таблице?

**P.S.**

```
    update_post_meta($order_id,'key1','ffdaasdf');
    wc_update_order_item_meta($order_id,'key2','fasdfsdf');
```

почему `update_post_meta` сохраняет данные, а `wc_update_order_item_meta` не сохраняет. проверял таблицы postmeta и order_itemmeta, данные сохранились только по ключу `key1` с помощью `update_post_meta`

Comment: Скорее всего, это пример денормализации базы данных, поэтому данные заказов хранятся отдельно (например, при изменении данных в товаре они не должны затронуть товар, уже оформленный ранее)

Comment: @lezhni, а конкретней можно по теме?
к примеру мне нужно хранить дополнительные данные заказа, как их правильно сохранять, в какой таблице?

Comment: Правильно - забыть эту идею лезть в базу руками. WC сейчас в каждой версии добавляет свои новые таблицы, чтобы уйти от WP-таблиц типа postmeta. Ваши усилия накроются с 90% - вероятностью в новой версии WC. Используйте методы WC для сохранения нужной информации.

Comment: @KAGG Design, я и прошу как раз пример того, как правильно работать с добавлением новый данных к заказу. `update_post_meta($order_id,'ffff','ffdaasdf');` это работает, а это нет `wc_update_order_item_meta($order_id,'aaaaaa','fasdfsdf');`

Comment: `wc_update_order_item_meta` почему эта функция не сохраняет данные? проверял таблицу и postmeta и order_itemmeta, ничего не сохранилось, а с помощью функции `update_post_meta` данные сохраняются в `postmeta`

Comment: я и не собирался на прямую вносить изменения в таблицы через sql

Comment: @KAGG Design, подскажите, получается, что для сохранения данных в таблицу `order_itemmeta`, нужно сначала узнать `order_item_id` с помощью `order->get_items()`, а потом использовать `wc_update_order_item_meta ` ?

Comment: с помощью `update_post_meta` не нужно делать таких действий и выглядит проще, ведь `update_post_meta ` не изменится в ближайшее время

Comment: Делайте всё через функции wc, например, `wc_update_order_item_meta`. Не трогайте базу руками!